# PayPal: Switch between multiple option boxes?

Tags: jquery, paypal

I've been doing some reading up on how to use PayPal forms. I've created a form to use options, but I want to be able to switch between two dropdown boxes depending on whether they select Option A or Option B...

(The only question I found that is remotely close is -- [Creating Multiple Select Option Box in Paypal Shopping Cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801989/creating-multiple-select-option-box-in-paypal-shopping-cart) -- and I don't understand it.)

Here is some example code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" data-abide>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="matt.roberts.33@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="MRobertsDesign_BuyNow_WPS_CA">
    <input type='hidden' name='lc' value='CA'>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mrobertsdesign.ca/design/payments/completed/">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://mrobertsdesign.ca/design/payments/cancelled/">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="service-plan">

    <input type="text" placeholder="What is your name?" id="pack_name" name="os1" maxlength="100">

    <select id="pack_type" name="item_name">
        <option value="">Choose a plan:</option>
        <option value="Basic">Basic - Starting at $90</option>
        <option value="Advanced">Advanced - Starting at $190</option>
    </select> 

    <!-- Options A (Basic) -->
    <select id="pack_time" name="os0">
        <option value="">Choose your hours:</option>
        <option value="2hrs">2 Hours - $90.00</option>
        <option value="3hrs">3 Hours - $180.00</option>
        <option value="4hrs">4 Hours - $228.00</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="2hrs">
       <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="90.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="3hrs">
       <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="180.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="4hrs">
       <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="228.00">

    <!-- Options B (Advanced) -->
    <select id="pack_time" name="os0">
        <option value="">Choose your hours:</option>
        <option value="2hrs">2 Hours - $190.00</option>
        <option value="3hrs">3 Hours - $240.00</option>
        <option value="4hrs">4 Hours - $328.00</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="2hrs">
       <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="190.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="3hrs">
       <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="240.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="4hrs">
       <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="328.00">

    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Client">
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Hours">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button radius payments-buy" value="Buy Now">
</form>
```

The idea is that when someone chooses Basic or Advanced:

```
    <select id="pack_type" name="item_name">
        <option value="">Choose a plan:</option>
        <option value="Basic">Basic - Starting at $90</option>
        <option value="Advanced">Advanced - Starting at $190</option>
    </select>
```

It will change the dropdown options to either A or B, respectively.

Now I'm not sure how to go about this, anyone have any ideas? I'm not sure if you understand what I'm doing but please ask me if you need more clarification, I'm not sure what else I can say.

I understand PHP a little more so I get the idea... When Someone clicks on that dropdown box and chooses either Basic or Advance, it needs to trigger a jQuery script that will first do a check to see what's been clicked then loop through the values from an array and populate the form. I just don't know how to do this, any one wanna give it a shot?

---

For the sake of example, I'm pretty much trying to get the JS/jQuery version of this psuedo-php code:

```
<select id="pack_type" name="item_name">
    <option value="">Choose a plan:</option>
    <option value="Basic">Basic - Starting at $90</option>
    <option value="Advanced">Advanced - Starting at $190</option>
</select> 

<?php
    // I know this doesn't work but for the sake of example
    if (select.pack_type option.basic.selected) {
        var $pack_type = 'basic';
    } elseif (select.pack_type option.advanced.selected) {
        var $pack_type = 'advanced';
    } else {
        var $pack_type = NULL;
    }

    // Basic
    $plan['basic'][] = array(
        'hours' => '2 Hours', 
        'price' => '90.00',
    );
    $plan['basic'][] = array(
        'hours' => '3 Hours', 
        'price' => '120.00',
    );
    $plan['basic'][] = array(
        'hours' => '4 Hours', 
        'price' => '250.00',
    );

    // Advanced
    $plan['advanced'][] = array(
        'hours' => '2 Hours', 
        'price' => '190.00',
    );
    $plan['advanced'][] = array(
        'hours' => '3 Hours', 
        'price' => '220.00',
    );
    $plan['advanced'][] = array(
        'hours' => '4 Hours', 
        'price' => '350.00',
    );

    // Other variables
    $i = 0;

    if ($pack_type == 'basic') {
        // Echo basic
        echo '<select id="pack_time" name="os1"><option value="">Choose your hours:</option>';
            foreach ($plan['basic'] as $prices) {
                echo '<option value="' . $prices['hours'] . '">' . $prices['hours'] . ' - $' . $prices['price'] . '</option>';
            }
        echo '</select>';
        foreach ($plan['basic'] as $prices) {
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="option_select' . $i++ . '" value="' . $prices['hours'] . '"><input type="hidden" name="option_amount' . $i++ . '" value="' . $prices['price'] . '">';
        }
    } elseif ($pack_type == 'advanced') {
        // Echo advanced
        echo '<select id="pack_time" name="os1"><option value="">Choose your hours:</option>';
            foreach ($plan['advanced'] as $prices) {
                echo '<option value="' . $prices['hours'] . '">' . $prices['hours'] . ' - $' . $prices['price'] . '</option>';
            }
        echo '</select>';
        foreach ($plan['advanced'] as $prices) {
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="option_select' . $i++ . '" value="' . $prices['hours'] . '"><input type="hidden" name="option_amount' . $i++ . '" value="' . $prices['price'] . '">';
        }
    } else {
        // Echo nothing
        echo '<select id="pack_time" name="os1"><option value="">Choose your hours:</option></select>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to show a payment button to people who want basic, and another one for those who want advanced? Why not make 2 pages with one button each and let use navigate to the respective pages upon selection. That would be the easiest way. Did you check if paypal has this option from their side? I guess they have an option to allow users to select from multiple options.

Comment: No, I want one payment button, it's just a dropdown or radio buttons or whatever I could have there, but the idea is that when people choose `Basic` or `Advanced` it will trigger a jQuery event and call a script to populate `<select id="pack_time" name="os0">...</select>` and `<input type="hidden" name="option_selectN" value="X"><input type="hidden" name="option_amountN" value="Y">` with the appropriate values

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ has help on how to do it!

Comment: @Kishor They don't have the option to do this, as far as I can find any way unfortunately... that is a good idea though, to just make 2 fully separate forms. I just wanted to see if it could be done this way really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal gives you an option to have selection dropdowns of products, with different prices.

1. Login to paypal.
2. Go to Profile Select 'My Selling Tools'
3. Click on Update next to 'Manage my payment buttons'
4. Create a new button
5. Tick the checkbox with 'Add drop-down menu with price/option'
6. And you will get a screen as in the image below.

[image]

**ADD : Here is a jsfiddle, that might help what you are trying to achieve. A drop down, which will show and hide seperate buttons upon selection.**

Jquery

```
    $('select.div-toggler').change(function(){
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).children().addClass('hide');
    var show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
    $(show).removeClass('hide');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TLBvx/61/

Comment: Thanks, I've already coded that above myself, I've just added an extra drop down. The problem is that I want to switch between two different dropdown menus and PayPal does not give an option to do that.

Comment: 2 different drop down menus? Why exactly?

Comment: Not that it matters, but because I have two different packages with two different lists of pricing

Comment: Then, may be doing like this would be an option. You have 2 packages A and B, each having products with $10 and $20. Make 2 buttons with $10 and $20 drop downs. And make a dropdown in your site manually,which has option A and B. Once A is selected in the drop down, display the code for first button, so that has the dropdown made by paypal. Same for option B.

Comment: Great idea, that's what I'm asking for help accomplishing. I've coded that above.

Comment: Your code technically works, it's just not what I'm looking for, I've written some make-shift PHP code as an example of what I'm trying to do and stuck that at the bottom of my question if you want to take a look!